# How to find Sum Of Pivoting two columns in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, find, sum, pivot

I am using following procedure to retrieve total `presents` and `absents` by using pivot query....i want to `SUM` of `Presents[P]` And `Absents[A]` And then `calculate percentage`

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAttendence](@Course_Id varchar(30), @Semester varchar(10))

```
AS
   SELECT DISTINCT Enroll_Number, Course_Id, Semester, Isnull([P],0) 
                                           As Presents, Isnull([A],0) As Absents

    FROM (SELECT Enroll_Number, Course_Id, Semester, Flag from Attendence ) ps
    pivot(Count(Flag) for Flag in ([P],[A])) as pvt 

    WHERE Course_Id = @Course_Id and Semester = @Semester
```

This is `Forula` to implement....

Sum = Presents + Absents

Percentage = ((Presents / Sum) * 100)

Comment: How about adding `A+P as SumAP` to the field list?

Comment: Mikael - Where i can place it ? if possible please give me example....thanks

Comment: I meant in the field list `select distinct A+P, Enroll_Number, Course_Id ...`. Your query looks a bit suspicious. If you could add the table structure with some sample data and expected output perhaps someone could come up with an alternative query for you.

Comment: And by "suspicious" I mean the `distinct` keyword, the use of `isnull` and the where clause on the main query where I would suspect it to do better in the sub query.

Comment: Mikael - `A+P As Total` works fine...how can i find `percentage` as formula given above ? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Enroll_Number,
       Course_Id,
       Semester,
       P as Presents,
       A as Absents,
       P+A as SumPA,
       1.0*P/(P+A)*100 as Percentage
from
  (
    select Enroll_Number, Course_Id, Semester, Flag
    from Attendence
    where Course_Id = @Course_Id and 
          Semester = @Semester
  ) ps
pivot
  (
    count(Flag) for Flag in ([P],[A])
  ) as pvt
```